# Cropping Canny edge detection image

Tags: image-processing, crop, canny-operator

I have scanned images of A5 pages. In the scan they only take up half the page and I want to remove the parts with nothing in it.
I have used canny edge detection to get the edged image and now was wondering how I could crop it so the resulting image is the area within the 4 corner pixels.
[image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roEcq.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome. Can you add a little more detail please? A sample image also helps. Firstly, and the ROIs (Regions of Interest) "square" in the image? I.e. perfectly horizontal/vertical? Secondly, what language are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've attached a sample image to the original question. I'm just starting out so I thought I would try with a square image first but I want to build up to images that are off centre too.
I'm using Google Colabs so python.

Comment: Okay, python and I think, from seeing `.imshow()`, you are using opencv?

Comment: Yes I am using opencv

Comment: And finally... sorry, please replace the image with the original scan and I'll take a look for you. Basically however, you just need to find the boundbox of your edges, set the image ROI to that rectangle, and copy it.